# Set automatically height of Textbox that i add from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to set height of multitext,textbox automatically with below code but doesn't work

```
//behind Code

TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
txt.Text = ...
txt.ID = ...
txt.ReadOnly = true;

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "changeSHeight", "changeSHeight('" + txt.ClientID + "');", true);


//javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
         function changeSHeight(f) 
         {
             var e = document.getElementById(f);
             e.style.height = e.scrollHeight + "px";
         }
    </script>
```

i check `changeSHeight` that it getting called correctly

when i want to show `scrollHeight` with `alert` doesn't show anything,the problem is that because i add textboxes from code behind ,this line:`var e = document.getElementById(f);` can't find them

Comment: what is the value of `scrollHeight`? can you log it to console to see its value?

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#idofdiv").bind("resize", function() {
   if($('#idofdiv').height() > 200){ $('#idofdiv').css('height','auto'); }
});

});
```

this might help you
this is jquery code

Comment: if you are using asp.net id of your div will be change in aspx.page view generated id of your din in view page source use same id..

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use 
height: auto; property if css it will automaticaly change the height of div..

Comment: i add these textboxes to `AjaxAccordion` and each time,first i add  `div` and add textbox to div and set `height` to `auto` for div but doesn't wotk